# ostream problems c++

Tags: c++-cli, ostream

im not sure why i am having problems with ostream. If i use using namespace std; it throws up a bunch more errors like linker errors.

This is my code where i am having problems and the errors.

```
virtual void Put (ostream&) const;

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream'
error C2065: 'ostream' : undeclared identifier
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream'
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream'
```

this is the container .h header file where i am having problems with

```
#ifndef CONTAINER_H
#define CONTAINER_H
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Object.h"
#include "NullObject.h"
#include "Ownership.h"
#include "Iterator.h"
#include "Visitor.h"


class Container : public virtual Object,  public virtual Ownership
{
protected:
unsigned int count;

Container ();
public:
virtual unsigned int Count () const;
virtual bool IsEmpty () const;
virtual bool IsFull () const;
//  virtual HashValue Hash () const;
virtual void Put (ostream&) const;
virtual Iterator& NewIterator () const;

virtual void Purge () = 0;
virtual void Accept (Visitor&) const = 0;
};

#endif
```

if i use

```
virtual void Put (std::ostream&) const;
```

it fixes the errors however, in the proceeding .cpp file i get the same errors above in the put function. i did try the std:: in the put functions but it threw up a ton of linker errors. i tried to use namespace std; also but that throws up a ton of linker errors.

```
#include "Container.h"
#include "NullIterator.h"
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>


Container::Container () :
count (0)
{}

unsigned int Container::Count () const
{ return count; }

bool Container::IsEmpty () const
{ return Count () == 0; }

bool Container::IsFull () const
{ return false; }

Iterator& Container::NewIterator () const
{ return *new NullIterator (); }

void Container::Put(ostream&)const

{ 
    return;

}
```

heres the errors i now get in that container.cpp file

```
error C2065: 'ostream' : undeclared identifier
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

i tried to #include fstream

I will appreciate any help here. theres a ton more code but i dont think you need to see the other files.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forget the std namespace. ostream is declared in std namespace, so you need to add "using namepsace std" before the declaration of Container or use scope resolution (std::ostream).

Comment: You have declared: class Container : public virtual Object,  public virtual Ownership. Why do you use virtual here?

Comment: Sometimes it makes more sense for the derived class D to contain only one instance of the base class A. In C++ this is accomplished using virtual base classes :

class A { ... };
class B1 : virtual public A { ... };
class B2 : virtual public A { ... };
class D : public B1, public B2 { ... };

Comment: I think, you should provide linker errors here, as std namespace reference is absolutely needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Container::Put(ostream&)const

{ 
    return;

}
```

I'm still a little new at this, but don't you need a variable name here?

Comment: No, you don't. Moreover, if you name an unused variable, compiler will issue a warning.